# Browser autocomplete issue

Tags: reactjs, browser, antd

I am having a hard time trying to find a proper way to disable autocomplete from browser in antd forms.

In normal form inputs
`<Input autoComplete="none" />`

works perfectly.

the problem is that in Select and Autocomplete components it does not work, it does not accept this prop, the question is:

is it posible to disable browser autocomplete in the whole form?, I have been browin for hours for an answer to this issue, and so far all I found is that it is not posible, but just want to give it last try asking here.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is, Set autoComplete 'off' to the entire form.

```
        const handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
               //... Submit Actions
        }


       return (
        <form autoComplete='off' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
               // ... form contents ...              
        </form>    
       )
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I forgot to mention that that does not work neither :(